# How to check internet connectivity using j/query

Tags: jquery, popup, alert

I have html document which I'm using in localhost.In localhost I have to detect whether internet connection  is available or not using jQuery. If internet is not available then popup should show to inform about internet nonavailability.

I did this in JavaScript by using `var online = navigator.onLine;`
but I want to do it now with jQuery with popup.Please advice how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those javascript techniques are not quite reliable, maybe you could try to make an ajax call to a server side script like PHP that is checking a website header like www.google.com and determine the internet status by timeout or header information.

You might need to re-configure your local server to access external websites though

Answer (score 0):

[You can use Offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/)

Offline.js is a library to automatically alert your users when they've lost internet connectivity, like Gmail.
It has a number of beautiful themes and requires no configuration.